# I have History.js problems in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, history.js

It seems that there's a problem with the way History.js is instantiated, but I'm unsure even about that. On window load, this code (among others) is called:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'anchorchange', function(event){
```

and for this code on IE8 I get:  Unable to get value of the property 'Adapter': object is null or undefined.

You can see the page at skrobotwp.gandzo.com, everything works fine in newer browsers.

Comment: I´m having the same problem, have you found any solution?

Comment: ok, just found the solution. on IE8, History.js needs to be initialized after page load. just add an $(document).ready(function...)

Comment: Will check it out and let you know, thanks for the suggestion